# How to maintain a data in android

Tags: android

Can you guys give me some idea on how can I maintain a certain progress? I'm developing a game that has 10 stages, per stage it has a number of questions and whenever the user finished all the number of questions on a certain stage, he/she can now proceed to the next stage. now what i want to happen is if the user for example achieved or unlocked the 2nd stage, when he/she exits the game and when he/she opened it again, the user will see the last progress which is on the 2nd stage. Im a newbie in android.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If data you want to persist is simple primitive data types, you can use shared preferences
Or if you want to save big data use files or you can save objects as well.

Comment: I mean if i'm on stage2 for example and I want to quit the game, if i press the home button and open the game again, it will return to stage 2 not on stage 1 or whatever stage the user last finished.

Comment: any one has a solution for this?

Comment: Use "shared preference" to store user current stage of game and in starting of game you can check from which level you have to start the game.
Can't it be implemented in this way for your game ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save all your important data into:

- `sharedPreferences`
- `db` such as sqliteDb
- External `files`

It depends on how many informations you need to store. If you have only one single information such `stage=2`, you can save it on a shared pref and read every time the main activity start.
If you need to store more infos such `username, skill, features, weapon, etc` maybe a DB is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bundle savedinstancestate object to save your state. For that there is two events
onSavedInstanceState and
restoreSavedInstanceState

```
@Override
 public void            onSaveInstanceState(Bundle
 outState){
  super.onSaveInstanceState
  (outState);
  outState.putString
   ("key", "value");
   }





 @Override
protected void
onRestoreInstanceState
(Bundle
savedInstanceState) {
situation =
savedInstanceState.
getString
("key");
super.
onRestoreInstanceState
(savedInstanceState);
}
```